# Strange behaviour of "underneath" accents and \rowcolor

Tags: accents, colortbl

The following example shows the problem using the `\b` command for the "bar-under" accent: it seems to interact in an unexpected way with `\rowcolor`. Uncommenting the appropriate `\renewcommand` line, the example shows also a bad interaction with `\c` (for the "cedilla"), and `\d` (for the "dot-under" accent):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcommand*\CRow[1]{\rowcolor{blue!30}\b#1\\}
%\renewcommand*\CRow[1]{\rowcolor{blue!30}\c#1\\}% uncomment for cedilla
%\renewcommand*\CRow[1]{\rowcolor{blue!30}\d#1\\}% uncomment for dot-under

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
  \CRow{a}
  \CRow{b}
  \CRow{c}
  \CRow{d}
  \CRow{e}
  \CRow{f}
  \CRow{g}
  \CRow{h}
  \CRow{i}
  \CRow{j}
  \CRow{k}
  \CRow{l}
  \CRow{m}
  \CRow{n}
  \CRow{o}
  \CRow{p}
  \CRow{q}
  \CRow{r}
  \CRow{s}
  \CRow{t}
  \CRow{u}
  \CRow{v}
  \CRow{w}
  \CRow{x}
  \CRow{y}
  \CRow{z}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

What is causing the problem and how to avoid it?

Comment: I wonder whether has something to do with David Carlisle's comment in the [`colortbl` package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/colortbl/colortbl.pdf) regarding `\rowcolor`. Moreover, he refers to `\rowcolor` as a "mechanism"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As egreg has pointed out in a comment to the answer of Alan Munn the `colortbl` package uses `\everycr` or, more precisely, an alias `\CT@everycr` to insert a specific token list after every `\cr` and effective `\crcr`:

```
\let\CT@everycr\everycr
\newtoks\everycr
\CT@everycr{\noalign{\global\let\CT@row@color\relax}\the\everycr}
```

In essence, this configuration causes `\rowcolor` to set the background colour for the current row, but not for subsequent ones.

The macro `\b` and friends are based on `\ialign` which is defined in the LaTeX kernel:

```
\def\ialign{\everycr{}\tabskip\z@skip\halign}
```

Obviously, `\ialign` provides for the case that `\everycr` is used; it does, however, not provide for the case that `\CT@everycr` is used instead of `\everycr`.

As a result, if `\b`, `\c` or `\d` appear in a row initiated by `\rowcolor` they might implicitly reset the background colour before the end of the row. You can prevent this by means of an adequate new column type:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\makeatletter

\newcolumntype{-}{%
  >{\CT@everycr{}}%
}

\makeatother

\newcommand*{\CRow}[1]{%
  \rowcolor{blue!30}\b#1&\c#1&\d#1\\%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{-c-c-c}
  \CRow{a}
  \CRow{b}
  \CRow{c}
  \CRow{d}
  \CRow{e}
  \CRow{f}
  \CRow{g}
  \CRow{h}
  \CRow{i}
  \CRow{j}
  \CRow{k}
  \CRow{l}
  \CRow{m}
  \CRow{n}
  \CRow{o}
  \CRow{p}
  \CRow{q}
  \CRow{r}
  \CRow{s}
  \CRow{t}
  \CRow{u}
  \CRow{v}
  \CRow{w}
  \CRow{x}
  \CRow{y}
  \CRow{z}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The resulting output is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on the cause of the problem and for providing a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a partial answer, and a workaround. It's somehow dependent on the font and the encoding. If you load `fontenc` with the T1 encoding, and use `\c` you one more correct glyph: the `t`, although it has no effect on the `\b` or `\d`.  The following quote from TeX by Topic is also probably relevant (p.47)

> No genuine under-accents exist in TeX. They are implemented as low
>   placed over-accents. A way of handling them more correctly would be to
>   write a macro that measures the following character, and raises or
>   drops the accent accordingly. The cedilla macro, `\c`, in plain TeX does
>   something along these lines. However, it does not drop the accent for
>   characters with descenders.

I'm not sure how this interacts with the `\rowcolor` command, though.

Notice that in Plain TeX if you do:

```
\setbox0=\hbox{\c c}
\showbox0
```

you get:

```
> \box0=
\hbox(4.30554+1.70137)x4.44444
.\kern 0.0 (for accent)
.\tenrm ^^X
.\kern -4.44444 (for accent)
.\tenrm c
```

But if you do one of the characters that doesn't work, you get:

```
\setbox0=\hbox{\c t}
\showbox0

> \box0=
\hbox(6.15079+1.70137)x3.8889
.\vbox(6.15079+1.70137)x3.8889
..\hbox(6.15079+0.0)x3.8889
...\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
...\hbox(6.15079+0.0)x3.8889 []
...\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
..\glue(\baselineskip) 0.0
..\hbox(0.0+1.70137)x3.8889
...\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
...\hbox(0.0+1.70137)x3.8889, glue set 999.72223fill []
...\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
```

As a workaround, you can use XeLaTeX (doesn't work with LuaLaTeX, for some reason.) The effect is still font-dependent, however.  If you just use the default font with XeLaTeX (Latin Modern) you get a different effect than when you use it with pdfLaTeX: none of the cells are black, but some of the glyphs are completely missing (b, h, k, l, n, r and z).  Very odd. Notice, however, that it is these glyphs that also show a slightly smaller underbar in the XeLaTeX output below. I don't think this is an accident.

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine}
\newcommand*\CRow[1]{\rowcolor{blue!30}\b#1\\}
%\renewcommand*\CRow[1]{\rowcolor{blue!30}\c#1\\}% uncomment for cedilla
%\renewcommand*\CRow[1]{\rowcolor{blue!30}\d#1\\}% uncomment for dot-under

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
  \CRow{a}
  \CRow{b}
  \CRow{c}
  \CRow{d}
  \CRow{e}
  \CRow{f}
  \CRow{g}
  \CRow{h}
  \CRow{i}
  \CRow{j}
  \CRow{k}
  \CRow{l}
  \CRow{m}
  \CRow{n}
  \CRow{o}
  \CRow{p}
  \CRow{q}
  \CRow{r}
  \CRow{s}
  \CRow{t}
  \CRow{u}
  \CRow{v}
  \CRow{w}
  \CRow{x}
  \CRow{y}
  \CRow{z}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Alternatively, you can use the `tipa` package (without XeLaTeX) and use `\textipa{\b a}` etc.

Comment: Alan, thank you for the answer and for the workaround. I'll start a bounty to see if someone can explain why there's a bad interaction with `\rowcolor`.

Comment: @Gonzalo That seems like a good idea. Maybe my answer will help those with more knowledge (and time) than me actually explain the effect.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the fact that `\b`, `\c` and `\d` use `\halign` and **colortbl** plays with `\everycr`. One can say `\cellcolor{...}` for cells with those "accents".